# Set both track and thumb colors for on and off state for UiSwitch in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiswitch

I want to have a switch with the colors reversed for On and Off state.
Say in ON state, thumb color = blue and track color = red, then in OFF state I want to have thumb color = red and track color = blue.

How do I implement this in xamarin.iOS. (not forms).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
UISwitch uISwitch1 = new UISwitch();
uISwitch1.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(100,100,30,50);
uISwitch1.ThumbTintColor = UIColor.Red;
uISwitch1.Layer.CornerRadius = (nfloat)(uISwitch1.Frame.Height / 2.0);
uISwitch1.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
uISwitch1.OnTintColor = UIColor.Red;

//Detect switch value changed
uISwitch1.ValueChanged += UISwitch1_ValueChanged;

private void UISwitch1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    var s = sender as UISwitch;
    bool state = s.On;
    if (s.On)
    {
        s.ThumbTintColor = UIColor.Blue;
    }else
    {
        s.ThumbTintColor = UIColor.Red;
    } 
}
```

For more info, you could refer to [UISwitch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch?language=objc)

This is the result for on and off state:

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps!